# mod_rewrite using rewritten name instead of original

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

This is probably a pretty basic question for anyone familiar with mod_rewrite, but I'm not so here it is:

I am trying to redirect urls from `baseurl/school/<name>` to `baseurl/school/result.php?name=<name>`. My .htaccess currently looks like this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^school/([^/]+)/?$ school/result.php?name=$1 [NC]
```

I make a test request to `baseurl/school/aoeu`. The request is rewritten, but the result.php script reports the value of `$_GET['name']` to be "result.php", not "aoeu". I tried changing the `GET` variable to something other than "name" but the issue persisted.

Comment: What about this: `RewriteRule ^school/([^/]+)/?$ /school/result.php?name=$1 [L,NC]` ? Also, you should avoid using `/?`which will lead to duplicate content (you have to choose with or without trailing slash)

Comment: Unfortunately, The `L` did not help. Good idea about the `/?` though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add some conditions to prevent looping. The rewrite engine continues to run the rules until the resulting URI stops changing. Try:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^school/([^/]+)/?$ school/result.php?name=$1 [NC]
```